# How to print a string to replace the value of the labels in unsupervised learning

Tags: python, python-3.x, label, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I am using `sklearn.cluster.KMeans` to categorise data. By printing my labels, I can see that `KMeans` is working, However, the labels are printed as numerical values (0, 1, or 2).

After this, I want to reprint the labels as strings, such as "narrow", "wide" and "normal".

This is my attempt using `if-elif` statements:

```
csv= "data.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(csv, header = None, low_memory = False)
model = KMeans(n_clusters = 3, random_state = 1)
model.fit(data)
labels = model.predict(data)
print(labels)
for category in lables:
    if category == 0:
        print('narrow')
    elif category == 1:
        print('wide')
    elif category == 2:
        print('normal')
    else:
        print('Unlabeled Data')
np.savetxt("category.csv", category, delimiter = ',')
```

Comment: And presumably you get the `print` output you want? `print`ing to stdout does not change the underlying data (it's just throw-away output); I assume you actually want to `map` categories to to the DataFrame column that contains numerical values (or whatever structure you have that you're iterating through)

Comment: Please show some snippet of output from `print(labels)`. Is it a numpy array, a pandas DataSeries, other?

Comment: My labels look like this when I print them [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 2 ... 0 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 2 2 0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` just writes your output to stdout, it doesn't change the underlying data. The output is throw-away. You use "print" multiple times in your question when I think you want to actually modify the data. One way to do this would be to use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html).

```
import numpy as np

labels = np.array([0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0]) # Fake data

# Now use select to replace the numerical values with categories
replacements = ['narrow', 'wide', 'normal']
new_labels = np.select([labels == 0, labels == 1, labels == 2],
                       replacements)
```

I'm not entirely sure what optimisations `numpy` can give here because I didn't specify a dtype for the output array (like I might with an accumulator) and we're going from a numerical type to a string type. It's possible that this just drops out as a python loop and there's no benefit from this syntax over treating it like a regular list, and mapping the integers to categories from a dictionary by iterating. The syntax certainly doesn't lend itself to more categories than you use in your question.